# Why wasn't Hermione's enchanted purse affected by the Thief's Downfall?

Tags: harry-potter, gringotts

Now we all know that it had been established in book one and confirmed again in book seven that Gringotts is not a place to mess around with unless you are a really skilled or very accomplished Dark Wizard.

For instance, while going to the Lestrange's vault in the hope of finding a Horcrux, the bank cart was forcefully passed through the Thief's Downfall, a sort of magical waterfall which wipes out all magical enchantments, thus making the thief extremely vulnerable and prone to easy capture by the guards.

Now the funny thing is that, while the effect of Polyjuice Potion was removed from Hermione and Ron, Hermione's enchanted purse didn't burst open after going through the enchanted water.

Why did this happen? Any theories?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The relevant quote from the book:

> “The **Thief’s Downfall**!” said Griphook, clambering to his feet
> and looking back at the deluge onto the tracks, which, Harry knew
> now, had been more than water. “It **washes away all enchantment,
> all magical concealment**! They know there are impostors in Gringotts,
> they have set off defenses against us!”
> <sup><sub>—*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 26, *Gringotts*</sub></sup>

Hermione, hearing this, instantly checks her bag:

> Harry saw Hermione **checking that she still had the beaded bag**,
> and hurriedly thrust his own hand under his jacket to make sure he had not lost the Invisibility Cloak
> <sup><sub>—*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 26, *Gringotts*</sub></sup>

We know from the beginning of the chapter that Hermione had tucked it away safely

> It was now packed
> inside the beaded bag, which, Harry was impressed to learn, Hermione
> had protected from the Snatchers by the simple expedient of
> **stuffing it down her sock**.
> <sup><sub>—*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 26, *Gringotts*</sub></sup>

Here is the key moment that answers your question:

> she pointed Bellatrix’s wand at the waterfall and cried, “Protego!”
> They saw the Shield Charm **break the flow of enchanted water** as it
> flew up the passageway.
> “Good thinking,” said Harry. “Lead the way, Griphook!”
> <sup><sub>—*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 26, *Gringotts*</sub></sup>

### Conclusion

The waterfall has to actually touch the enchanted object (in the case of the Polyjuice potion effects, it washed over the people). From Hermione checking for her beaded bag, we can assume she had it safely tucked away and it didn't get washed by the waterfall, and then they used her Shield Charm to break the flow of the waterfall and get away without it being washed.

---

### Alternate ideas and conjecture

Early on in the *Deathly Hallows* book, we are introduced to the beaded bag, and are fed a potentially key (to this question) piece of information

> to Harry and Ron’s utter
> astonishment, she pulled out a pair of jeans, a sweatshirt, some
> maroon socks, and finally the silvery Invisibility Cloak.
> “How the ruddy hell — ?”
> “**Undetectable** Extension Charm,” said Hermione. “Tricky, but I
> think I’ve done it okay; anyway, I managed to fit everything we need
> in here.”
> <sup><sub>—*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 9, *A Place to Hide*</sub></sup>

We have very little canonical information, evidence or basis to make any assumptions about [Goblin magic](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Goblin_magic), but it's possible that Hermione's **Undetectable** Extension Charm on her beaded bag made it so the Thief's Downfall didn't detect (and therefore didn't wash away) the extension charm.

That being said, Griphook assures us that it washes away "**all** enchantment, **all** magical **concealment**", so we have, both, the mystery of Goblin magic and Griphook's word working against us in this hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about Hermione performing the shield charm :)

Comment: This seems like a very ineffective security device if all a thief has to do to bypass it is wear a raincoat.

Comment: @BradleyUffner They probably bank (pun not intended) on mystery. Even with Griphook the trio were never informed to wear raincoats prior to the heist.

Comment: @GhotiandChips that's called security by obscurity and generally speaking, it's not very effective.

Comment: @stannius: In this case, it has to work only once (which it did), thus Security by Obscurity was working here...

Comment: The shield charm is most likely to protect the re-imperioused Bogrod, not to protect the purse, which goes right back into Hermione's robes, where it would be safe again, if that was how the Theif's Downfall worked.

Comment: @arc_lupus, work only once? I don't think Gringotts stops operating after the events of *Deathly Hallows*. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez - Well, the idea is that anyone who is intruding in Gringotts dies a horrible death. So, it only has to work once per intruder, because they aren't ever going to get to spread the news.

Comment: @EvSunWoodard OK, I get it now, but it's still relying on having a 100% success rate, which is proven false by Harry and friends.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez - That's true. Also proven false by Voldemort in Book 1. I don't agree with this answer, but thought I would help explain anyway.

Comment: @EvSunWoodard You have succeeded at making clear your claim and disagreement with my answer, by saying that "The shield charm is most likely to protect the re-imperioused Bogrod", but what you haven't succeeded in is presenting evidence, proving this claim, or otherwise giving reasons as to why it's plausible. More to the point, you've not succeeded at explaining why it is a more reasonable claim than the one I proposed. I, for one, consider Hermione/Harry's immediate reactions (checking bag+shield charm) to be evidence. Imperiusing Bogrod again would not have been a problem—

Comment: [continued]— just as it wasn't a problem when they went through it the first time. I'm more than happy to a) Be wrong, but I am even happier if b) the evidence is so compelling that it outcompetes the evidence that supports my own opinion, because that means I can change my opinion to an even stronger one. Thus far, I must admit I can't say I find my own opinion to be challenged by the evidence presented, though I look forward to your response in light of my latest replies.

Comment: @GhotiandChips - unfortunately, I do not have the book in front of me, however, having read the books countless times what I can say is that: the invisibility cloak and the handbag are unaffected by the thieves downfall. Both Harry and Hermione check and find nothing. Hermione exclaims, "Harry!", and Harry sees that Bogrod is no longer under the imperious curse. At this point, Harry imperiouses Bogrod again, then Hermione preforms the shield charm and all five of them walk under the falls. My explanation is that they wouldn't want to risk losing Bogrod who is their only way into the vault.

Comment: @EvSunWoodard The fact that Hermione and Harry's items remain unaffected is actually an argument **for** my answer. Seeing as they had it tucked away, out of harm's way, it only strengthens the claim that the water has to touch whatever enchantment it wishes to wash away (this is why the Polyjuice potion effect and Imperius curse ceased). I'm not even necessarily disagreeing that breaking the flow of water would add convenience because they wouldn't have to Imperius Bogrod anymore, however it does nothing to counter-argue my claim. They could easily Imperius him after walking past it.

Comment: Suffice to say I remain unconvinced, but the forum remains open, the stage is yours, should anything compelling surface.

Comment: @GhotiandChips - If you read my answer, the evidence is that NO magic cares about clothing in the entire book, except the Thieves Downfall, if you are correct. Whereas secrecy sensors are fooled by putting things in the wrong bottle in the sixth book. So, there is already a standard that some magic relies on intent, whereas all spells and curses work through clothing. I think that the cloak being immune is also important, because it is clearly a concealment charm, which helps point out that it IS a deathly hallow to the reader, as the cloak of invisibility is immune to magic.

Comment: @EvSunWoodard I'm not sure that I follow your line of thought, but I wanted to update you that thanks to our conversation I went and skimmed through the book (*Deathly Hallows*) to see if I could find something. Indeed, I found 2 quotes, one which would support my own proposal, and 1 quote which I use to support a plausible alternate hypothesis, concerning Hermione's **Undetectable** Extension Charm. I recommend checking out this updated answer and leave your thoughts if you please.

Comment: @stannius *Security through obscurity isn't security* **by itself** you mean. Very very big difference.

Comment: I don't know that the Undetectable part is relevant. Rowling writes about it (she doesn't mention the word undetectable but she refers to the bag itself) but the way I interpret it it has nothing to do with making the charm itself undetectable or unbreakable: https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/extension-charms

Comment: Hermione wasn't checking to see if the enchantment on the bag had been removed; she was checking to see whether she had entirely lost the bag during the fall, as indeed the words you bolded state. And the Shield Charm was not in response to this; she did the Shield Charm as a response to the people she heard coming after them, presumably to obstruct them in some way.

Answer (score 11):

It is possible that it is because the undetectable extension charm is not considered concealment. Remember that in the sixth book Hermione points out that secrecy sensors do not work on everything. She notes that a potion in the wrong bottle is not considered a dark object. Likewise, the undetectable extension charm is considered a charm to give you more room, not a charm to conceal all the stuff in your bag.

Note that the undetectable extension charm provides ZERO protection to the items inside. Unlike moody's magical trunk, all of the items inside the bag are easily accessible, as Harry is able to access all the items inside while looking for dittany. The bag also does not prevent spells being used on the objects, as Harry ends up using a summoning charm on that same dittany. Also notice that Hermione does check to see if the bag is okay. She is unsure what will count as concealment too. I guess they just got lucky that undetectable extension doesn't cut it as a means of concealment.

**Conclusion:**
The bag is just not conceal-y enough to count.

Comment: Fair enough fan-theory, but then what'd be the point of Hermione breaking the flow of the waterfall with her shield charm? What'd be the point of her checking her bag in the first place?

Comment: I always assumed it was because he still needs Bogrod. The imperious curse lifts when they go through the water. Since they still have to go through with Bogrod in tow, they need to keep the water off of him.

Comment: @GhotiandChips - Also, as I said, she is checking her bag because she doesn't know whether or not it will be affected. It turns out to be safe, but she doesn't know that until after.

Comment: I don't think I follow the logic "Undetectable charm ≠ concealment", seems dauntingly counter-intuitive. As for "Note that the undetectable extension charm provides ZERO protection", I also don't follow this. Making something undetectable protects it from being .. detected. If it is truly useless in the realm of protection, I doubt Hermione would bother.

Comment: @GhotiandChips - I'm starting to worry you aren't reading what I'm writing. I think you are confusing "undetectable extension charm" with "undetectable, extension charm". The idea is that you can't detect that the bag has been extended from the outside, NOT that you cannot detect what is inside the bag. The bag is not designed for concealing items, which is why Harry can freely retrieve items from inside it, unlike Moody's trunk, which actively hides the contents. Therefore, the falls don't consider it a concealment charm, but a handy, space-saving charm.

Comment: Not that it matters, but in both scenarios, undetectable is a form of concealment (and by implication, protection against ... detection), whether it's the bag or the extension charm. :) It's not that I'm not reading what you're typing, your worries are unnecessary, it's that it makes no sense (to me, anyway).

Comment: What I'm saying is that some canonical magic is intent based. A secrecy sensor (a device which detects *secrecy*) does not react to a love potion in a different bottle (aka a hidden potion). So, it is not a reach, that the thief's downfall will not detect the extension charm. Because the point of the spell is to make more space in a confined area, the point is NOT to conceal what is inside. Therefore, like the bottled potion, the extension charm is not counted. Magic does not care about the name of other spells, only what they do. I don't know what else could be confusing you.

Comment: @GhotiandChips https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/extension-charms (see also quotes from the book in how Hermione hides the bag from the snatchers; also note that the enchantment in the car Arthur Weasley modifies isn't undetectable - that's relevant). I'm not sure that Hermione used the shield for the reason the OP suggested but you misunderstand the point and the OP is right here.